# Dynamic query in stored procedure doesn't return an error but fails to insert record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will insert records where column1 and column2 are "fixed", while column3, column4 and column5 changes. Sometimes there isn't even a column3 or a column4 or a column5.

This is the first time I'm using dynamic query in stored procedure and I'm stumped. Please help me see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert]
    @param1 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
    @param2 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
    @param3 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @param4 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @param5 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @col3 nvarchar(50) = NULL, --optional
    @col4 nvarchar(50) = NULL, --optional
    @col5 nvarchar(50) = NULL  --optional

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select ...)
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param1 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + @param1 + CHAR(39) + ';'
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param2 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + @param2 + CHAR(39) + ';'
            IF @param3 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param3 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + @param3 + CHAR(39) + ';'
            IF @param4 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param4 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + @param4 + CHAR(39) + ';'
            IF @param5 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param5 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + @param5 + CHAR(39) + ';'

            SET @QRY = @QRY + ' INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2' 
            IF @col3 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ', ' + @col3
            IF @col4 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ', ' + @col4
            IF @col5 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ', ' + @col5
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ') VALUES '
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ' (@param1, @param2 '
            IF @col3 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ', @param3'
            IF @col4 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ', @param4'
            IF @col5 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + ', @param5'
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ')'

            EXEC (@QRY)

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) 
                BEGIN  
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   
                    RAISERROR('Exception occurred. Transaction rolled back.',16,1)
                END
        END CATCH
    ELSE
        BEGIN  
            RAISERROR('Duplicate record found. Record not inserted.',16,1)
        END
END
```

If there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, please do enlighten me. Thank you!

**EDIT**:
I'm so sorry for the confusion. Yes there is a Begin and Commit in my code. Also, the column names of columns 3, 4 and 5 are passed as parameters to the stored procedure as well. That was why I opted to using dynamic query. I edited the code above accordingly. I'm so sorry for leaving out that very important part!!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Have you debugged what is in `@qry` before you try to execute it?

Comment: if you concatinate with a variable that is `NULL` then the whole concatination will also be null

Comment: maybe if you use  print (@QRY) and run it manually you could find out more

Comment: @GuidoG - Good spot, I thought all the variables were being checked before being concatenated, but `@param1` and `@param2` are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I can see *(Thanks to @GuidoG)* is that if `@param1` or `@param2` are `NULL` your `@QRY` string will be `NULL`.

You could replace these lines...

```
        SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param1 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + ISNULL(@param1, 'NULL') + CHAR(39) + ';'
        SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param2 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + ISNULL(@param2, 'NULL') + CHAR(39) + ';'
```

Personally, I'd skip the parameter parts anyway.  You're not escaping them, so are open to SQL Injection attacks and/or unexpected failures.

`sp_executesql` allows you to avoid those problems...

```
        SET @QRY = @QRY + ' INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2' 
        IF @param3 is not null
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ', column3'
        IF @param4 is not null
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ', column4'
        IF @param5 is not null
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ', column5'
        SET @QRY = @QRY + ') VALUES '
        SET @QRY = @QRY + ' (@param1, @param2 '
        IF @param3 is not null
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ', @param3'
        IF @param4 is not null
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ', @param4'
        IF @param5 is not null
            SET @QRY = @QRY + ', @param5'
        SET @QRY = @QRY + ')'

        EXEC sp_executesql
          @QRY,  
          N'@param1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @param2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @param3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @param4 NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @param5 NVARCHAR(MAX)',
          @param1,
          @param2,
          @param3,
          @param4,
          @param5
```

*(Even though you pass in all 5 parameters, only the ones you are interested in get used in the `INSERT`, and passing them as parameters prevents SQL Injection attacks, or the need to escape special characters, etc, etc.  Oh, and you're never at risk of concatenating `NULL`.)*

***EDIT:***

I also looked around to see if there was a better way to pick up column defaults.  Although I couldn't find anything "better", there is a "different" approach...

```
INSERT INTO
    tableName(
      column1,
      column2,
      column3,
      column4,
      column5
    )
SELECT
    @param1,
    @param2,
    ISNULL(@param3, MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column3' THEN COLUMN_DEFAULT END)),
    ISNULL(@param4, MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column4' THEN COLUMN_DEFAULT END)),
    ISNULL(@param5, MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column5' THEN COLUMN_DEFAULT END))
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'        -- or whatever it really is in your case 
    AND TABLE_NAME   = 'tableName'
;
```

That doesn't need Dynamic SQL at all.  But I'm not convinced that it's any better than Dynamic SQL.

***EDIT2:***

OH!!!

Your code shows a `ROLLBACK` in the error handling, which implies there's a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` in the code that you're not showing us?

Do you actually have a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` anywhere???

Comment: Yes, a missing `COMMIT` could just simply "swipe" the data under the rug and never store it to the table ..... good catch!

Comment: I went with the sp_executesql. I didn't know that dynamic queries in stored procedures are vulnerable to SQL injection. I just thought they're not since I'm still using parameters anyway. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Artemis - Concatenating strings to embed parameter values in a SQL string always has the same result; unless you jump through hoops, characters such as `'` in the string are going to cause you problems.  And those problems expose vulnerabilities.  Actual parameterisation is the most robust way to avoid those problems / vulnerabilities, whether you're building the SQL string in Python or in TSQL.

Comment: @Artemis - Having read your edit to the question, you use of parameters to define column names causes the same sql injection attack vulnerability.  You have to explicitly trust the source that's passing the column name, because if the source wanted to abuse it and run any arbitrary code, they could.  The better approach is to check the incoming column names against a list of acceptable values *(a white list)*.  Possibly even checking against the information schema, to check that the columns do actually exist.

Comment: @MatBailie - Will sp_executesql not protect me from sql injection attacks completely?

Comment: @Artemis A SQL Injection Attack is where user defined string are concatenated with SQL strings and then executed. The vulnerability is that the user defined string may itself include characters such as `'`, `;`, `--`, etc, which then allow malicious SQL code to be embedded in the string and executed by you. `sp_executesql` provides as mechanism for passing parameters (instead of concatenating strings) to prevent that from happening. But in your post you're still concatening strings for the column names, without checking them. If they contain SQL code, you're blindly executing that code.

Comment: I see. I will add checking for the columns. Thank you for explaining things clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your parameters for NULL, look at this example

```
declare @param1 nvarchar(10) = null
declare @QRY nvarchar(100)

set @QRY = 'test ' + @param1

select @QRY
```

the result will be `NULL` because one of the concatination values was null

So you should check for the presence of null and replace by the text 'NULL' or some other value
If we do that then our concatination will not be `NULL` anymore, look at this example again

```
declare @param1 nvarchar(10) = null
declare @QRY nvarchar(100)

set @QRY = 'test ' + isnull(@param1, 'null')

select @QRY
```

this will result in `test null`

Maybe that is where your problem lies

So I recommend changing this into

```
SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param1 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + ISNULL(@param1, 'NULL') + CHAR(39) + ';'
SET @QRY = @QRY + ' DECLARE @param2 nvarchar(MAX) = ' + CHAR(39) + ISNULL(@param2, 'NULL') + CHAR(39) + ';
```

Answer (score 1):

use sp_executesql and pass the parameters as parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert]
    @param1 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
    @param2 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
    @param3 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --optional
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX);

BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select ...)
            SET @QRY = N'INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2' 
            IF @param3 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + N', column3'
            SET @QRY = @QRY + N') VALUES '
            SET @QRY = @QRY + N' (@p1, @p2 '
            IF @param3 is not null
                SET @QRY = @QRY + N', @p3'
            SET @QRY = @QRY + N')'

            exec sp_executesql @QRY, N'@p1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @p2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @p3 NVARCHAR(MAX)', @param1, @param2, @param3;

    END
END
```

`@param...` are local stored proc parameters. `@p1`... `@px` are dynamic SQL context parameters. Is OK to pass extra params not used (`@p3` when NULL).

Also your BEGIN TRY ... CATCH transaction handling is incorrect. See http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/ for the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are doing this to insert the default values for columns 3,4,5

This way is much simpler and prevents injection

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert]
    @param1 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
    @param2 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
    @param3 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @param4 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @param5 nvarchar(MAX) = NULL  --optional

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select ...)
        BEGIN TRY

            SET @QRY = 'INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) 
                VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5)'
            IF @Param3 IS NULL
                SET @QRY = REPLACE(@Qry, '@Param3', 'DEFAULT')
            IF @Param4 IS NULL
                SET @QRY = REPLACE(@Qry, '@Param4', 'DEFAULT')
            IF @Param5 IS NULL
                SET @QRY = REPLACE(@Qry, '@Param5', 'DEFAULT')
            sp_executesql @QRY, 
                 N'@param1 nvarchar(MAX), 
                 @param2 nvarchar(MAX),
                 @param3 nvarchar(MAX),
                 @param4 nvarchar(MAX),
                 @param5 nvarchar(MAX)',
                 @param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) 
                BEGIN  
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   
                    RAISERROR('Exception occurred. Transaction rolled back.',16,1)
                END
        END CATCH
    ELSE
        BEGIN  
            RAISERROR('Dulicate record found. Record not inserted.',16,1)
        END
END
```

if the optional parameters are null, your dynamic sql will look like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) 
VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

Which is completely valid

Answer (score 0):

I personally get goosebumps when I see such complex dynamic SQL code for such a relatively simple use case.

It seems that you just want to insert two to five field values in a new record in one of your tables.

My most important question here is if those three optional fields have any default values other than NULL (by using a DEFAULT constraint). If so, I would provide those default values as the default values of your stored procedure parameters as well.

And I would remove the default values from the first two mandatory parameters.

And I would change the body to use just a simple insert statement instead of all that complex dynamic SQL stuff.

Something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert]
    @param1 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @param2 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @param3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @param4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL, --optional
    @param5 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Some default value other than NULL'  --optional
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
            VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) 
                BEGIN  
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   
                    RAISERROR('Exception occurred. Transaction rolled back.', 16, 1);
                END;
        END CATCH;
    ELSE
        BEGIN  
            RAISERROR('Dulicate record found. Record not inserted.', 16, 1);
        END;
END;
GO
```

But this is just my personal preference...

Extra note:

I really like your SP structure in which you set any preparation statements before the first BEGIN statement. I personally always use a BEGIN...END block after the AS, but your way you can add an extra separation between preparation and execution. Nice. ;)

Comment: I partly agree, but stored procedure parameters and table columns does not have the same behavior when it come to nullability, default values, constraints, etc.... If that things are already constrained in the database schema, any change implies do it in the stored procedures too. If just something like ISNULL(@Param, DEFAULT) would be valid, our lives would be easier...

Comment: True. But it isn't valid. So you need a workaround or a redesign. I just gave my best (shortest and simplest) alternative as I see it.

Comment: Just an opinion, neither down-vote nor criticize, I prefer to write something little more complex if It helps me to win maintainability. That way you also need to add logic to the applications that call your procedure on when they need to send or skip the parameters.

Comment: Yes, I understand the dilemma. But that's why I simply try to avoid DEFAULT constraints altogether, since IMHO those do not contribute to the data structure and integrity at all. IMHO, the client logic should be responsible for data population/entry and the database for data integrity checking. If Artemis does not use any DEFAULT constraints on those fields (which I hope), everything is quite fine. Besides all that, I assume that a stored procedure with static SQL performs better than one with dynamic SQL too. That's why I would take those duplicated defaults (when necessary) for granted.

Comment: I think is already using defaults, is the only possible reason to try the insert in that way

Comment: Yes, you may be right about that. Another solution (which would require considerable client-side modifications) is to execute a simple INSERT query and pass DEFAULT instead of NULL for unknown field values. That way there is no need for a stored procedure at all. However, that does require that the query should be constructed dynamically by the client application. As you say, it's mainly an opinion-based decision. IMHO, all provided solutions - including yours - can be pretty well maintainable.